# undefined<br/> - Javascript - DOM - checkboxs

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

Dispongo de un `select` con cuatro opciones, puedo elegir las que quiera, al pulsar el `button` "enviar" se debe enviar el texto de las opciones seleccionadas a una `div`.

Éste es mi código:

```js
//Función que crea una caja con los datos del resumen. Se debe crear usando DOM.
function crearCajaResumen() {
  //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos, sea <p> o <div> o <form>, etc.
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  //DIV tiene la propiedad style, la cual permite acceder a atributos CSS. Ejemplo: div.style.width = "280px"; ...
  div.setAttribute("style", "width: 280px; height: 170px; background-color: #FE775A; float: left;");
  //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <body>
  //var variable = document.getElementsByTagName("etiqueta")[posicion];
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  //Añadimos al documento body un hijo llamado "div".
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <center>
  var center = document.getElementsByTagName("center")[0];
  //Insertamos el elemento "div" antes que el "center".
  body.insertBefore(div, center);
  //Creamos un nodo de texto que agregaremos al div.
  var titulo = document.createTextNode("DATOS RESUMEN FORMULARIO:\n\n");
  //Añade un nuevo nodo al final de la lista.
  div.appendChild(titulo);
  //Creamos un nodo de texto que agregamos al div.
  var contar = document.createTextNode("Has seleccionado " + contar_seleccionados() + " elementos.");
  div.appendChild(contar);
}

var texto_opciones = ["Analisis y programacion", "Hardware, redes y seguridad", "Administracion de bases de datos", "Telecomunicaciones"];
var textos_seleccionados = "";
//Función que cuenta los checkboxs seleccionados (marcados).
function contar_seleccionados() {
  //Guardamos en una variable los checkboxs (un array) del elemento <form> con la propiedad checkbox.
  var checkboxs = document.getElementById("miformulario").getElementsByName("prefe");
  var contador = 0;
  //Recorremos el array y guardamos en una variable los checkboxs seleccionados.
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
    
    if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
      contador = contador + 1;
      textos_seleccionados = textos_seleccionados + texto_opciones[i] + "<br/>";
    }//Cerramos el for para que me acepte la correcion
  }
  console.log(textos_seleccionados);
  console.log(contador);
  return contador;
}


// **Manejo de eventos "onclick" y métodos enviar.**
miformulario.btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  return confirmEnviar();
}, false);

function confirmEnviar() {
  var pregunta = confirm("¿Deseas enviar el formulario?");
  if (pregunta == true) {
    deshabilitar_btnEnviar();
  } else {
    //No hacer nada.
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function deshabilitar_btnEnviar() {
  miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviando...";
  setTimeout(function() {
    miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviar";
    //Llamada a la función crearCajaResumen();
    crearCajaResumen();
  }, 3000);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="miformulario">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align=left colspan=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u>Selecciona tus Preferencias:</u></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=right></td>
      <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="si" colspan=3>Analisis y programacion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=right></td>
      <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="si" colspan=3>Hardware, redes y seguridad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=right></td>
      <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="si" colspan=3>Administracion de bases de datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=right></td>
      <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="si" colspan=3>Telecomunicaciones</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

¿Por qué me selecciona bien las opciones marcadas pero no se muestran los textos?

Y éste el error por consola:

> funciones.js:446 `undefined<br/>undefined<br/>undefined<br/>undefined<br/>`
>   funciones.js:447 4

Comment: Define el array texto_opciones y textos_seleccionados dentro de la funcion o pásaselo como parámetro, no lo lee porque está fuera.

Comment: "textos_seleccionados" no es una array, es un String. Los textos de las opciones del select están guardados en el array "texto_opciones".

Comment: Tienes razón, me equivoqué de nombre. Corregido. Defínelos dentro de la funciónigual que la var contador.

Comment: Tengo el mismo error, y lo declaro fuera para poderlo utilizar en otras funciones pero tampoco me funciona ni incluyéndolo dentro. Creo que ese no es el error.

Comment: He puesto tu código como ejecutable dentro de la pregunta, y no se ve el error que comentas. De todos modos, hay algunas cosas que no se ven "correctas" en el código: al hacer las operaciones de forma asíncrona (con el `setTimeout`), puede darse el caso de que las opciones seleccionadas no coincidan entre el momento que se da al botón y el momento en el que se ejecuta el código.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Mira esta imagen: http://subefotos.com/ver/?8f6053795b9f3911ea3871a7c21c7cf3o.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los textos que quieres rescatar, ***DEBEN*** ir en el atributo `value` de los inputs, como los tienes tu no tienen nada que ver con los checkbox, todos tienen el valor `value="si"`. Si es solo Javascript puedes probar :

```js
// **Manejo de eventos "onclick" y métodos enviar.**
miformulario.btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  return confirmEnviar();
}, false);

//Función que crea una caja con los datos del resumen. Se debe crear usando DOM.
function crearCajaResumen() {
  //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos, sea <p> o <div> o <form>, etc.
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  //DIV tiene la propiedad style, la cual permite acceder a atributos CSS. Ejemplo: div.style.width = "280px"; ...
  div.setAttribute("style", "width: 280px; height: 170px; background-color: #FE775A; float: left;");
  //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <body>
  //var variable = document.getElementsByTagName("etiqueta")[posicion];
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  //Añadimos al documento body un hijo llamado "div".
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <center>
  var center = document.getElementsByTagName("center")[0];
  //Insertamos el elemento "div" antes que el "center".
  body.insertBefore(div, center);
  //Creamos un nodo de texto que agregaremos al div.
  var titulo = document.createTextNode("DATOS RESUMEN FORMULARIO:\n\n");
  //Añade un nuevo nodo al final de la lista.
  div.appendChild(titulo);
  //Creamos un nodo de texto que agregamos al div.
  //var contar = document.createTextNode("Has seleccionado " + contar_seleccionados() + " elementos.");
  
  var seleccionados = [];
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("prefe");
  for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           seleccionados.push(inputElements[i].value);
      }
  }
  var contar = document.createTextNode("Has seleccionado " + seleccionados.length + " elementos.");
  var salto = document.createElement("br")
  div.appendChild(contar);
  div.appendChild(salto);


  seleccionados.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
      var salto = document.createElement("br")
      var val = document.createTextNode(value);
      div.appendChild(salto);
      div.appendChild(val);
  });
}

function deshabilitar_btnEnviar() {
  miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviando...";
  setTimeout(function() {
    miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviar";
    //Llamada a la función crearCajaResumen();
    crearCajaResumen();
  }, 3000);
  return false;
}

function confirmEnviar() {
  var pregunta = confirm("¿Deseas enviar el formulario?");
  if (pregunta == true) {
    deshabilitar_btnEnviar();
  } else {
    //No hacer nada.
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="miformulario">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td align=left colspan=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u>Selecciona tus Preferencias:</u></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right></td>
              <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="Analisis y programacion" colspan=3>Analisis y programacion</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right></td>
              <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="Hardware, redes y seguridad" colspan=3>Hardware, redes y seguridad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right></td>
              <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="Administracion de bases de datos" colspan=3>Administracion de bases de datos</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right></td>
              <td align=left><input type="checkbox" name="prefe" value="Telecomunicaciones" colspan=3>Telecomunicaciones</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu código sioesi, pero no puedo utilizar jQuery, lo siento. Sólo puedo utilizar DOM.

Comment: Te deje una opcion sin Jquery!, saludos

Comment: Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿cómo añado los saltos de línea y cómo agrego los textos_seleccionados a mi div?

Comment: edito @omaza1990

Comment: sioesi, abre chat por favor.

Comment: ¿Cómo integro los textos marcados en las opciones, cuales están guardados en la variable "textos_seleccionados", en el div, en mi función "crearCajaResumen()"?

Comment: Edite, no es necesario contarlos, ya que los agrego a un arreglo por lo tanto llamando a la funcion `length` se cuantos hay, por otro lado, al recorrerlos tengo los valores de los textos, echa un ojo a mi respuesta

Comment: Lo vi ahora mismo. ¿Por qué cada vez que ejecuto o clickeo en "Enviar" me crea cajas nuevas? Quiero controlar que sólo sea una, y se vaya actualizando.

Comment: Sorry, es que copie tu codigo para que funcionara hay que ver porque se duplica!

Comment: Cada vez que hago click en "Enviar" se llama a crearCajaResumen(), lo cual te crea una nueva caja, y la situa lo más arriba que puede y flotando a la izquierda de cualquier elemento que lo hubiera... ¿valdría un... if (exists....)?

Comment: CLARO, PODRIAS EVITAR QUE EXISTA DOS VECES, O LO MEJOR SERIA ELIMINARLA

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58967/discussion-between-sioesi-and-omaza1990).

Comment: Habría que utilizar... ¿removeChild?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías reiniciar la variable nada mas entrar en el método, si no se te van a ir acoplando los resultados nuevos con los del anterior cada vez que le des al botón. Me faltaría ver como llamas a los métodos, lo he pegado en un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46fev65o/) y me funciona perfectamente.

Añade el código del botón y su `onClick`

**EDICION**

En la linea `document.getElementById("miformulario").getElementsByTagName("input")` estas sacando todos los `inputs` del formulario, y aunque compruebes que tenga `name='prefe'` la variable `i` se va incrementando, de tal manera que cuando llega a los `checkbox`, la variable `i` alcanza un valor superior al tamaño del `Array` y al pasarse te saca `undefined`

La linea debería quedar `document.getElementById("miformulario").getElementsByName("prefe")`

Comment: Código que pides ya está adjuntado pero creo que en ello no está el error. No sé porque me sale "undefined" a la hora de leer los textos.

Comment: Con el código o modificación que me ofreces, no me detecta ningún error undefined pero... ¡no funciona! Cómo quedaría el método contar_seleccionados(), edita a ver la diferencia.

Comment: Me sigue quedado el mismo error. Mira la imagen: http://subefotos.com/ver/?8f6053795b9f3911ea3871a7c21c7cf3o.png

Comment: Acabo de modificarlo

Comment: Ahora sí me funciona y no sé ni qué he cambiado jajaja. Una pregunta: ¿ahora cómo hago un salto de línea para que se ordene en el div? ¿con \n o <br/>?

Comment: Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar el `document.getElementById("miformulario").getElementsByTagName("input")` por `document.getElementsByName("prefe")` para meterlos con salto de linea utiliza <br> pero tienes que insertarlo como `HTMLNode` no `TextNode` como textNode igual te vale el \n

Comment: Hictus, está bien que encuentres fallos en el codigo del autor pero no deberias editar la pregunta para cambiar el estado original . Si es muy necesario, comentaselo al autor para que él lo haga.

Comment: Como tenia el código completo en la pregunta, se lo edite para que pudiera copiar y pegar, pero si, tienes toda la razón, no es muy buena practica. Never again :)